# List with toggle div show/hide

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, toggle

The idea is that the user can either download the file by clicking download or view it as a png in browser by clicking open/show/whatever.

I used a solution found on here to achieve a show/hide toggle div function. It worked perfectly for one list item, but I'm trying to find a way to use this with a list of about 30 entries. I know I could just copy and paste the code and make new classes for the divs and anchors but surely there's a better way. I'm new to web development so I apologise if the solution is an obvious one.

Here is an example. I want each entry to control it's own div toggle (click on open).

```js
$('.list-link').click(function() {
  $('.test-div').show(500);
  $('.list-link').hide(0);
  $('.Hide').show(0);
});

$('.Hide').click(function() {
  $('.test-div').hide(500);
  $('.list-link').show(0);
  $('.Hide').hide(0);
});
```

```css
.list-entry {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

.test-div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: none;
}

.Hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-entry">
    <p> test 1</p>
    <div class="links">
      <a class="download-link" href="">download</a>
      <a class="list-link">open</a>
      <a class="Hide">hide</a>
  </li>
  <div class="test-div"></div>
  <li class="list-entry">
    <p> test 2</p>
    <div class="links">
      <a class="download-link" href="">download</a>
      <a class="list-link">open</a>
      <a class="Hide">hide</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <div class="test-div"></div>
  <li class="list-entry">
    <p> test 3</p>
    <div class="links">
      <a class="download-link" href="">download</a>
      <a class="list-link">open</a>
      <a class="Hide">hide</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <div class="test-div"></div>
</ul>
```

https://codepen.io/pen/RwgaxRQ

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A link to CodePen is great, but please always include the relevant code in your question so that people don't need to go off-site to understand your code.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited the post to do exactly that and got the message that you beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you require you can use jQuery's DOM traversal methods, such as `closest()` and `find()`, to relate the element that raised the `click` event to those around it which you want to affect.

Also note that your HTML is invalid. `ul` can only contain `li` elements, not `div`, so you need to change the structure slightly.

With that said, try this:

```js
$('.list-link').click(function() {
  let $li = $(this).closest('li');
  $li.find('.test-div').show(500);
  $li.find('.list-link').hide();
  $li.find('.Hide').show();
});

$('.Hide').click(function() {
  let $li = $(this).closest('li');
  $li.find('.test-div').hide(500);
  $li.find('.list-link').show();
  $li.find('.Hide').hide();
});
```

```css
.list-entry {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

.test-div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: none;
}

.Hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-entry">
    <p> test 1</p>
    <div class="links">
      <a class="download-link" href="">download</a>
      <a class="list-link">open</a>
      <a class="Hide">hide</a>
    </div>
    <div class="test-div"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-entry">
    <p> test 2</p>
    <div class="links">
      <a class="download-link" href="">download</a>
      <a class="list-link">open</a>
      <a class="Hide">hide</a>
    </div>
    <div class="test-div"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-entry">
    <p> test 3</p>
    <div class="links">
      <a class="download-link" href="">download</a>
      <a class="list-link">open</a>
      <a class="Hide">hide</a>
    </div>
    <div class="test-div"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Also note that I updated the demo to use jQuery v3.6.0, as 2.1.4 is very outdated.

Comment: Thanks! This works, but it's slightly clunkier than the original codepen version because I had to add flex-wrap to the li element to make the div appear below on the actual website. It's a lot smoother with the div outside the li element like in the original codepen. When you say having a div element in a ul is invalid, what consequences could there be? And if none, would it be possible to achieve the same result with the div outside the li element?

Comment: I took out the transition time to get rid of the clunkiness. Thanks a lot, this was very helpful.